# Python Simple Multiple Client Socket Server

Tags: python

I am wondering how I can make a simple socket server in Python 2.7 which can handle and add/accept multiple clients at a time. I do not want to use Twisted nor threading, nor any libraries; just Python, and sockets. I have looked around SoF (stackoverflow- is that a thing?) and found people asking the same question but not getting a clear answer.

If you are wondering why I need to do this, It's because I want to create a simple data forwarder which forwards client data to another server. I think a very simple example showing me Server.py, Client1.py, and Client2.py is just what I need. Again, just a very simple example with no threading, no twisted, no libraries.

I hope you can help me, I'm fairly new to Python and I feel like this project will help get me on my feet, and I learn great from examples.

Comment: If you want the server to handle multiple clients at one time you won't be able to avoid using multi-threading

Comment: If I've done it in PHP, I'm damn positive I can do it in Python!

Comment: So when the server is handing a request from one client, and a second client request arrives what do you want to happen? If you have only 1 thread then any subsequent requests that arrive will have to sit in a queue and wait to be processed one at a time - it would be possible to do it this way, but your users would hate you.

Comment: That's kind of what I'm asking SoF. Maybe something like a while loop which checks if it's getting a new client request, if so accepts it, and listens to all other clients

Comment: If you wanna go totally old-school, use `select`

Comment: By `nor any libraries` do you mean third-party librarys or even the standart library? So if you want to work with `sockets` you will need to `import socket` in python. If you do this you can also `import SocketServer`, i think this module will provide something you can work with: https://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html

Comment: @codebox Processing requests in a multi threaded environment can become extremely complicated to lock, maintain and debug. Single threaded asynchronous programming is usually preferred for that reason. The most common libraries for asynchronous programming (twisted, gevent, asyncio) also work that way. It is still possible to add threading afterwards to boost the performance, but the main event loop still runs in a single thread.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) (available for python 3.3 and later).

Asyncio is the new python standard for single-threaded concurrent programming:

> This module provides infrastructure for writing single-threaded concurrent code using coroutines, multiplexing I/O access over sockets and other resources, running network clients and servers, and other related primitives.

The documentation provides a few examples:

- [TCP echo client](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html#tcp-echo-client-protocol)
- [TCP echo server](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html#tcp-echo-server-protocol)

---

If you're not ready to migrate to python 3, you can use [trollius](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/trollius/), the portage of asyncio for python 2. There is a few differences between the two modules, as listed in the [documentation](http://trollius.readthedocs.org/en/latest/using.html):

> - replace asyncio with trollius (or use import trollius as asyncio)
> - replace yield from ... with yield From(...)
> - replace yield from [] with yield From(None)
> - in coroutines, replace return res with raise Return(res)

---

Other solutions for single-threaded concurrent programming on python 2.7:

- [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/): a coroutine-based Python networking library that uses [greenlet](http://greenlet.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).
- [asyncore](https://docs.python.org/2/library/asyncore.html#module-asyncore): built-in asynchronous socket library ([echo server example](https://docs.python.org/2/library/asyncore.html#asyncore-example-basic-echo-server)).

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7 and I plan on keeping it that way. Check the edit I'm about to make to the OP

Comment: @RoyalScripters Edited.